# Where Clause is not working in Update but working in Select in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to execute the below update query

```
update custom_field cfe set cfe.field_value =:valueId where  cp_entity_id = :cId
```

0 rows updated.

This is not updating any row but same where clause is working fine with select query and returns 1 row

```
select * from custom_field where cp_entity_id = :cId
```

Also, if i hardcode the value of cId parameter then update works fine but I am executing it from java program so it's not possible for me to hardcode the value

Also cp_entity_id column is a foreign key.

Comment: Are you running the query and hard-coded update from a session where you *inserted* that row too, and just haven't committed? The Java session won't see uncommitted data from other sessions.

Comment: No Row is already present there I am just trying to update

Comment: So you can query it from Java too, both hard-coded and with the bind? How about updating it from your IDE/client using a bind variable? Showing the data and the code around your Java call (setting the variable etc.) might be helpful too.

Comment: I am using Oraclesqldeveloper with the same bind parameters and there also update is not working

Comment: Please add your code and data to the question. (I'm guessing you're binding the columns in the wrong order, but who knows....)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I faced similar issue.
Use this
`select primary_key from custom_field where cp_entity_id = :cId`  query to find out primary key and Then use that primary key in your where clause of update query.

Comment: Seems like some limitation with OraclesqlDevloper IDE

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to set parameter is explained [here.](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jdbc/sample-jdbc-preparedstatement-sql-update)

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
  "UPDATE Messages SET description = ?, author = ? WHERE id = ? AND seq_num = ?");

// set the preparedstatement parameters
ps.setString(1,description);
ps.setString(2,author);
ps.setInt(3,id);
ps.setInt(4,seqNum);

// call executeUpdate to execute our sql update statement
ps.executeUpdate();
ps.close();
```